# Firebase Firestore is not creating a doc - any idea how to debug?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been struggling with a weird error. Can't create a doc in firebase. There are no security rules to speak of, just:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Firestore is initialised the normal way and is active:

```
import { Firebase } from "../db";
let firebase = Firebase();
let firestore = firebase.firestore();
```

But nothing happens after this is run other than printing "here1", the other consoles aren't doing anything and the userid doc is not being created and no collection and doc under it.

```
export const addEnquiry = async (data) => {
  let user = await firebase.auth().currentUser;
  data.uid = user.uid;

 console.log("here1");
  const enquiry = await firestore.collection("users").doc(data.uid).collection("enquiries").doc();
 
  return await enquiry
    .set(data)
    .then((doc) => {
console.log("here2");
      
      return true;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
console.log("here3");
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
};
```

The above doesn't print anything other than "here1" and gets stuck on the setting of the doc. The doc isn't created in Firestore either.

Any idea what might be wrong and how to debug it? Wasted a good 4 hours on trying to figure it out and worried if Firestore is so buggy that it's unsafe to use it in production.

Comment: add to your code how you insatiate the Firestore class as well. If you provide more of your actual code we may be able to pinpoint your bug

Comment: Where are you running your example from and how are you providing credentials?

Comment: I've expanded on the example, it's standard initialisation and the failure happens on the setting. The second of the firestore commands doesn't produce its intended effect, just silently failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's super weird, but what solved the issue for me is adding an unnecessary doc.get() like so:

```
export const addEnquiry = async (data) => {
  let user = await firebase.auth().currentUser;
  data.uid = user.uid;

 console.log("here1");
  const enquiry = await firestore.collection("users").doc(data.uid).collection("enquiries").doc();
 
  const x = await firestore.collection("users").doc(data.uid).get(); 
// ^^^ added the above line I don't actually need, but somehow it 
// establishes a connection to firebase or something which allows the 
// promise below to resolve, rather than just hang! 
// Doesn't resolve without it for whatever reason!

  return await enquiry
    .set(data)
    .then((doc) => {
console.log("here2");
    
      return true;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
console.log("here3");
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
};
```

When removing the line, the function hangs again. So have to keep it in for now!

A bit worrying that we have to use such workaround hacks to make a simple write to the firestore, to work, Firebase!

Nonetheless, hope it helps someone facing this undebuggable problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I assure you Firebase is not buggy at all, we have it running on several production applications and they're running fantastic.

Second, I think your issue here is that you're passing a function as the second argument in the set() method, which is nowhere that I can find in the [API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set). Instead, it returns a promise. Your code should look like this:

```
firebase.firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .doc(uid)
        .set({ uid: uid })
        .then((doc) => { console.log(doc.id) })
        .catch((err) => { console.log(err) })
```

Cheers.

Comment: Document set reference is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set

Comment: Appreciate your messages, but unfortunately it's made no difference - the doc is not being created at all! I've even switched off ALL security rules, back to read, write all and it's not writing it. If it's not a bug with firebase or its sdk, I don't know what it is then,

Comment: I just noticed I had an "await" on the function, try removing that. @Vlad

Comment: it's await in all of their examples, but i've tried without it. Still not working. I'm really lost as to what the issue might be other than firebase not working properly. I'm able to console.log(firestore) so it's connected fine, I can get the currentuser too, but I can't write anything!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which will work for you:

file test.mjs

```js
import { Firestore } from '@google-cloud/firestore';

const firestore = new Firestore()


export default (uid) => firestore.collection("users")
  .doc(uid)
  .set({ uid })
  .then(() => console.log('success')) // documentReference.set() returns: Promise < void >
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Comment: Do you see any differences with the code in the question? 
The only difference I see is that I'm using the npm firebase module:
```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
```

Comment: Are you initializing the firebase at any point, I don't see that here. Have you verified that `firebase.auth().currentUser;` has a value? As an FYI you don't need any of those awaits or the async. `collection.doc()` doesn't return a Promise. You are using `.then()` and return the promise in your `.set()` call.

Comment: firebase.auth().currentUser and even enquiry both return values and id's. It's when it comes to actually setting a doc, that it gets stuck without erroring or succeeding. The awaits don't make any difference, it doesn't work either way, but in their examples they use them: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#node.js_3

Comment: What I don't quite understand is why firebase doesn't respond, one way or another. It's just silent and never gets to then or catch. Is enquiry.set(data) possible to debug somehow? A promise that never resolves and no way of seeing what the issue is